# Cplex solution pool generates duplicate solutions

Tags: python-3.x, cplex, docplex

I put this question on IBM forum, since nobody responded I am going to ask here.
I have an MIP model written with docplex and a solution pool that populates a massive number of solutions.
My problem is, when my solution pool finishes most of the solutions are duplicated. In 1000 solutions there are only 4 unique solutions. I don't understand how and why this happens.
My solution pool settings is below:

```
    cpx = mdl.get_cplex()
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.intensity.set(4)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.absgap.set(1e75)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.relgap.set(1e75)
    cpx.parameters.randomseed.set(3)
    cpx.parameters.mip.limits.populate.set(20000)
```

Comment: Not answer yet, but discussion started at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=5557&MessageKey=cc37a3ff-7b39-4cde-8007-de1488613297